# flaskのアップロードされたcsvファイルを別のプログラムにつなげたい

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

flaskアプリでアップロードされたcsvファイルを読み込み、それをDataFrameに変換し、別のurlに送るかそのままダウンロードできるようにしたいです。現在は以下のようなコードでやっていますが、csvファイルをアップロードした時点で

```
Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

という表示が出てしまいます。どうにかできる方法を教えていただきたいです。

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/intern/upload'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'csv'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

#忘れたらflaskの公式見ればある
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            file=request.files['input_files']
            tempfile_path = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().name
            file.save(tempfile_path)
            df1=pd.read_csv(tempfile_path)
            return redirect(url_for('hello',
                                filename=df1))
```

---

追記

HTMLの部分について追記させていただきます。HTMLの部分は

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
```

のifに対してのreturnとして以下のようにしています。

```
return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

ダウンロードの部分は以下のようにしております。最終的に(/getPlotCSV)の方のcsvを'unfinished'ではなく、uploadの方で編集したDataFrameを変換したcsvに変えたいと考えております。

```
@app.route('/hello')

def hello():
    return '''
        <html><body>
        Hello. <a href="/getPlotCSV">Click me.</a>
        </body></html>
        '''

@app.route("/getPlotCSV")
def getPlotCSV():
    # with open("outputs/Adjacency.csv") as fp:
    #     csv = fp.read()
    csv = 'unfinished'
    return Response(
        csv,
        mimetype="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                 "attachment; filename=myanswer.csv"})
```

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[Upload and Download File using Flask in Python](https://buildcoding.com/upload-and-download-file-using-flask-in-python/)

Comment: HTML のフォーム部分も見せていただけますか？

Comment: 皆さん誠にありがとうございます！
返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。初めて使うもので勝手が分かっておりませんでした。
HTMLのフォームの部分として、本文の下に追記させていただきました。よろしくお願いいたします！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ここです！！

```
file=request.files['input_files']
```

ここを削除すれば動くはずです！せっかくすでに

```
file = request.files['file']
```

で正しいファイルを取得しているにもかかわらず存在していないキー名で再取得しようとしているのが原因でした。

---

#### 以下追加で直したほうがよいところ

1. HTML の要素名は「"（ダブルクォーテーション）」で囲まなければいけません。なので

   ```
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ```

   と書きましょう。
2. Python 内で使っている `file` という変数名は一般的すぎるのでもう少し説明的な名前がよいでしょう。また、Python 2.x では `file` という組み込み関数があったことからエディタでのシンタックスハイライトが効いてしまうなど混乱を招いてしまいます。`upload_file` などにしてみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: 質問箇所だけでなく、コード全体で直すべきところまで指摘していただき、本当にありがとうございます。またどこかで私の質問を見かけました時は、宜しくお願い致します。